# Using a case then in an insert statement

Tags: mysql

I want to insert some answer-dependent data into a mysql table. The first problem is that everytime I run the script, it fails:

```
INSERT INTO outgoing_sms (timestamp,dest_msisdn,text_message,sender_name,service_id)
VALUES (now(),last_inserted_number, CASE last_inserted_message
            WHEN 'no' THEN "you choose not to secure with payslip."
            WHEN 'yes' THEN "you choose to secure with payslip."
            ELSE "Invalid choice."
        END, 90294,0000002000099451);
```

Second question: Will mysql account for case sensitivity of "yes" / "no" or "YES" and "NO" or "Yes" / "No" or "yeS" / "nO".

My queries should be case-insensitive; it is enough that all characters are correct.

Comment: You may need to allow for all of those combinations, unless you intend to (as an example) use javascript to lowercase the text before sending it along.

Comment: How about [MySQL LOWER()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lower)

Comment: @RocketHazmat check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASE last_inserted_message WHEN 'no' THEN "you choose not to secure'

Comment: @Sharlike Thanks.I never knew that existed.

Comment: What you should be doing is inserting a dymmy value for 'yes' or 'no' into the table. This dummy value would have a corresponding mapping in an explanatory table. When you query the main table you do a join on the explanaotory table and you will get you messages.

Comment: @john Yaicks! That sounds like too much work.

Comment: Way less work in the long run. Good design is called good design for a reason. Easier to upkeep and manage. Also in this case, muuch simpler because you do not need to worry about case. Just save a dummy like 0/1.

Answer (score 0):

For the error, your syntax seems to be invalid. I do not have a mySql instance to test against, but this should work:

```
INSERT INTO outgoing_sms (timestamp,dest_msisdn,text_message,sender_name,service_id)
VALUES (now(),last_inserted_number, 
        CASE last_inserted_message
          WHEN 'no' THEN SELECT "you choose not to secure with payslip.";
          WHEN 'yes' THEN SELECT "you choose to secure with payslip.";
          ELSE "Invalid choice.";
        END CASE;,
     90294,0000002000099451);
```

The easiest way to take care of the lower casing is to do a dummy transformation to the data before submit, for ex. no = 0, yes = 1.